# Redirecting to a new page using jquery upon user confirmation

Tags: jquery

In my web application(using Zend Framework) when adding a new entity to the database, it should check whether this entity has previously been added and deleted. (When deleting an entity from the database, that particular record's "STATUS" column is updated to 0(zero).)

If the entity has deleted earlier, the system asks for confirmation to edit the previously deleted record, or add a new record. If the user needs to edit the previously added record, user should be redirected to the edit page.

This check and redirecting is done using jQuery. Here is the jQuery code I'm using:

```
 $("input[name=btnSubmit]").click(function(){       

    var name = $("input[name=txtTblPrefix]").val();
        var parameters = 'name='+name;

        $.ajax({
            url: '../admin_mapping/get-id',
            async:false,
            data:parameters,
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function(data)
            {       
                var res = confirm("There is a record already added to the database for "+name+". Do you want to edit it?");

                if(res)
                {
                    window.location.replace("../admin_mapping/edit?id="+data);
                }
            }

        });

    });
```

In this code, everything works perfectly other than the redirecting. I have tested the line `window.location.replace("../admin_mapping/edit?id="+data);` separately and it works fine. Even the `confirm()` function returns `true`.

I have tried putting an `alert()` inside the `if` condition, and the alert prompts. But the redirecting is not working.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the value of "../admin_mapping/edit?id="+data

Comment: it returns an integer. The value is returning. I have checked that as well

Comment: Use `window.location.href = "../admin_mapping/edit?id=" + encodeURIComponent(data)` instead?

Comment: nope......... it's not working either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I need to do is put a `return false` inside the `submit` function. Otherwise as the button is a submit button, the form gets submitted.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure the variable data contains what you expect: maybe it has some headers making the call go wrong (but you should spot this in the console).

If you can alert() the correct string, then try another approach: location has some security restrictions (i.e. an iframe cannot change its container's location); you may not be able to manipulate it in an unnamed function call, but you might be able to do so from a timeout (it worked for me!) so instead of

```
document.location.href='./yoururl?'+data
```

write

```
setTimeout("document.location.href='yoururl?"+data +"';",10);
```

this will run it in a wider scope and should succeed.

Comment: thanks for the answer...... This also works..but not the solution for my problem
I found it myself..... I need to put a `return false` inside the `submit` function as otherwise the form gets submitted.